# How to reduce the memory consumed by itertools.product?

Tags: python, python-3.x, refactoring, permutation

I am trying to generate all the permutations of a range of numbers(a,b) of size k and count the number of permutations whose sum is even. Currently my code is

```
highLow = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
k = int(input())
permutations = list(product(list(range(highLow[0],highLow[1]+1)), repeat=k))
print(len(list(filter(lambda x:sum(x)%2 == 0, permutations))))
```

But this is giving me a memory limit exceeded. How to solve this memory problem?

Comment: Simple: stop the `list()` thing!

Comment: a) try to avoid using list()  you normally don't need to create the full list, use the generator instead.  b) you should try to analyze this mathematically.   It is an even sum as long as you pick an even number of odd numbers.

Comment: As I [mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63425687/how-to-count-those-permutation-whose-sum-is-even-out-of-all-possible-permutation?noredirect=1#comment112154023_63425687), you'd better first solve this with math, not with code. You can then write code to do the math for you. But you shouldn't actually go through all "permutations".

Comment: Also, where is this problem from? Two guys asking about the same new problem at almost the same time...

Answer (score 2):

`product` uses O(1) memory; it's only your use of `list` to create a *list* of all the values that uses so much memory.

```
low, high = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
k = int(input())
permutations = product(range(low, high + 1), repeat=k)
n = sum(1 for _ in filter(lambda x: sum(x) % 2 == 0, permutations))
print(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

As chepner answered, `product` uses only O(1) memory. You can also solve your problem with O(**0**) memory for `product`, though, by not using `product` at all.

For example, the answer for `low, high = 1, 99` and `k = 100` is 18301617063661475246530801328625869309485603831946184570297868634965852237536237409359827175501347520033078455032642163735911784840089970792855267724585378713694517503049135418557489109958380424745001. With that method of filtering/counting `product`, that would take an eternity. With a little math, I computed that in less than a millisecond.

Yeah, this doesn't exactly answer the question as asked, but addresses the actual task. It's so common that people try to go through all permutations/combinations when they really shouldn't, that I think this is a useful answer.

Comment: superb rain, can you please explain the math you used?

Comment: Oh, so now you're suddenly interested in doing it with math, after ignoring my comments under your question?

Comment: And i accept the fact that there is no need to go through all the permutations if it can be solved with math.